# How to use a variable together with strings in replace() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, replace

It seems like the replace() method doesn't work when the searchvalue is strings concatenated with a variable.

***It seems like this issue is only present in the chrome browser. I would still appreciate help regarding this issue.***

I have tried using String().

```html
<p id="message">
  A blue ocean.<br> 
  A big ocean.<br>
</p>

Big: <input type="radio" name="adjective" value="big" id="big"> 
Blue: <input type="radio" name="adjective" value="blue" id="blue">

<script>
  var message = document.getElementById('message');
  var big = document.getElementById('big');
  var blue = document.getElementById('blue');

  big.onclick = blue.onclick = removeAdjective;

  function removeAdjective() {
    var adjective = this.value;
    var sentence = message.innerHTML;
    var toBeRemoved = "A " + adjective + " ocean.<br>";
    var newSentence = sentence.replace(toBeRemoved, '');
    message.innerHTML = newSentence;
  }
</script>
```

Expected result: the desired sentence is removed.

Actual result: nothing is removed.

I understand that there are workarounds in my example. My actual code is more complicated, and I actually have to find a solution to this for it to work.

Comment: Works for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/byexKJ

Comment: Works for me too. Is there another element with those ids message, big, blue in your actual code base?

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Oh, thats interestng. I need for it to work in a Chrome browser - only because this is what we use at school and what my teacher will use in the test tomorrow :)

Comment: @chamoda No, this is an example code and I have presented everything from it in the post. The issue seems to be with Google Chrome. Is there any way to make this work in chrome?

Comment: @FrederikVrålstad try adding a console.log(this.value) inside function. Does that print an empty string?

Comment: @chamoda No that prints the value of the pressed radio input.